# the error' name is nBSD related to sshd service

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I'm using linux shell. I tried to connect remotely to server from my local.  So I changed some setup in `sshd_config` at server.

permission root Login no -> yes

I typed `:wq` after I finished my change. But I just used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

Remote control didn't work well of course. I know now but not at that time. So i tried to change the server's setup again next to reboot. But the sshd service didn't work well since I rebooted

Now sshd service is not working, so I typed

```
service sshd restart
```

it gave me a message like this :

```
starting sshd:/etc/ssh/sshd_config : line 2 : Bad configuration option :nBSD :
/etc/ssh/sshd_config : terminating , 1 bad configuration options [FAILED]
```

I searched for a long time, but I couldn't get any information about that

Answer (score 1):

sshd is complaining about a bad line you added to sshd_config. Edit the file again, and carefully check line 2 (and nearby lines).